# Socket.io socket.emit() *randomly* not emitting on the same computer and browser

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm testing the client/server connection of an app relying on Node.js 0.12.0  and socket.io 0.9.6.

On the client side a simple:

```
window.onfocus = function () { 
       socket.emit('active');
};
```

and on the server side:

```
client.on('active', function (){           
    console.log('active');
});
```

No problems when I test this app locally.

When I test it online, the `socket.emit();` will randomly fail to work on the same computer and browser, ie when I reload my page I will see "active" in my logs, then I reload and see nothing, reload/nothing, reload/nothing, reload/"active", etc...

Any idea why this would happen on the same computer and with the same browser?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I have Avast installed on my computer, that I am forcing websocket communication, and that Avast blocks websockets (try to disable Avast and see if it solves your problem).

The problem has been reported to Avast more than five years ago but apparently nothing has changed : https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=68270.0

**Solution that worked best for me:**

- Use TLS/SSL (if you host your app on Heroku just access your app with https://...)

**Other possible solutions:**

- Use xhr-polling instead of websocket:

  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);

but for my app xhr-polling is too slow

- Try Sockjs instead of socket.io (untested, but recommended here https://www.robbritton.com/2013/12/10/why-we-ditched-socket-io)

Note that in the last version of socket.io xhr-polling is enabled by default so this bug should happen more rarely.

Related Stackoverflow posts:

[Socket.io 0.7.9 connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081642/socket-io-0-7-9-connection-issues)

[Socket IO WebSocket requests blocked by corporate firewalls.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852213/socket-io-websocket-requests-blocked-by-corporate-firewalls)